# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am faced with a peculiar error. All the frontend views is fully functional and all the sources are loaded, but for viewing the post with a certain id wont load.

Here is the route I have defined for it

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}/view', [\App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\PostController::class, 'view'])->name('posts.view');
```

And here is the view page when user clicks on the title it will will be redirected to `post.view`.

```
<a id="ctl01_dlNews1_Link1_0"  class="FBMitra" style="color:#DBA63C;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" href={{route('posts.view',$post->id)}} >{{$post->title}}</a>
```

Comment: I think you are missing the quotes in the href... try `href="{{route('posts.view',$post->id)}}"`

Comment: No href is ok  i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found the answer after 1 day of testing different routes and methods I fixed the error the error was related to the html code which caused the browser load in quirk mode here is the head of the html code before fixing :

and here is the solution which prevents the browser from loading into quirk mode which cause js,css or bootsrap no to load:
https://web.dev/doctype/?utm_source=devtools